# Parametric equations of straight line in cylindrical and spherical coordinates

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, vector-analysis

The most general equation of a straight line is

$$\vec{r}=\vec{r}_0+\vec{a} s$$

where $s$ is a parameter, the line passes through point $\vec{r}_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and is parallel to vector $\vec{a}=(a_x,a_y,a_z)$. In Cartesian coordinates, the parametric equations are

$$x(s) = x_0+a_x s$$
$$y(s) = y_0+a_y s$$
$$z(s) = z_0+a_z s$$

Write the parametric equations of this straight line in cylindrical and spherical coordinates, i.e. $r(s) = ...$, $\theta(s) = ...$, $z(s) = ...$
and in spherical coords. $r(s) = ...$, $\theta(s) = ...$, $\phi(s) = ...$

I tried using the conversion formulae (e.g. $\theta=\tan^-1(y/x)$ etc.) but arrived at long expressions. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates, from

$$r\cos\theta=r_0\cos\theta_0+sr_a\cos\theta_a,\\
r\sin\theta=r_0\sin\theta_0+sr_a\sin\theta_a$$

you draw
$$r^2=r_0^2+2sr_0r_a\cos(\theta_0-\theta_a)+s^2r_a^2,\\
\tan\theta=\frac{r_0\sin\theta_0+sr_a\sin\theta_a}{r_0\cos\theta_0+sr_a\cos\theta_a}.$$

This does not simplify further.